# Arrange items in list based on condition

Tags: python

Input is

```
list1 = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]
n = 3
```

And expected output is

```
[1, 4, 7, 2, 5, 8, 3, 6, 9]
```

I want to arrange the `list1` based on `n`.

Comment: post your attempts..

Comment: Am I the only one who doesn't understand the condition?

Comment: @Idos - It counts by threes - 1, 4, 7, then 2, 5, 8, etc.

Comment: so what is the answer for `n=4`?

Comment: 1. Iterate through your list
 2. find min & max
 3. add n to the min element and store it in a var
 4. if var is lower than max and exists in list append it in new list
 5. else proceed to next element and append.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

```
list1 = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9]
n = 3

m = len(list1)
list2 = [list1[x%(m-1)] for x in range(0, n*(m-1), n)]
list2.append(list1[-1])
print list2
```

% is the modulo operator. Basically the range statement iterates from 0 to 3 times the length of the list. The modulo operator crops the iteration to the right number within the length of the list. Unfortunately the last entry of the list cannot be reached with this method as x%(m-1) will be zero then. Therefore the last entry must be treated separately.

Comment: so for `n=4` it is `[1, 5, 1, 5, 1, 5, 1, 5, 9]`

Answer (score 1):

Use [`zip()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#zip) in this case?

```
>>> [list1[i:i+n] for i in range(0, len(list1), n)]
[[1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6], [7, 8, 9]]

>>> list(zip(*[list1[i:i+n] for i in range(0, len(list1), n)]))
[(1, 4, 7), (2, 5, 8), (3, 6, 9)]
>>>
```

Comment: >>> `n=4` `[(1, 5, 9)]`

Comment: @xi_: So what should it gives when `n=4`?

Comment: something like : [1, 5, 9, 2, 6, 3, 7, 4, 8] ?

Comment: @GerardRozsavolgyi: That makes no sense...However OP didn't say what's the expect output if `n` is `4`.

Comment: it's the result of appending one every four elements starting at pos 0 then starting at position 1, then pos 2, then pos 3 but as far as we haven't a clear spec ...

Answer (score 1):

What about:

```
list1 = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9]
n = 3
res = []
for i in range(n):
        res += list1[i::n]
print(res)
```